# Magento 2 etc folder location for Development

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm developing using Magento (2.3) for the first time.

I am building a Widget which goes hand in hand with an API.

The structure I believe will work under app/code is:

```
- /Company
  - /Product
    - /Api
      - registration.php
      - /etc
        - di.xml
        - module.xml
        - webapi.xml
    - /Widget
      - registration.php
      - /etc
        - module.xml
        - widget.xml
```

Will this work? Or does the /etc folder have to come up one level like this:

```
- /Company
  - /Product
    - /etc
      - di.xml
      - module.xml
      - webapi.xml
      - widget.xml
    - /Api
      - registration.php
    - /Widget
      - registration.php
```

If this is the case, how do I deal with the multiple module.xml files? can I place multiple "module" elements in the "config" element?

EDIT 1
So it needs to be:

```
- /Company
  - /Product
    - registration.php
    - /etc
      - di.xml
      - module.xml
      - webapi.xml
      - widget.xml
    - /Api
    - /Widget
```

Can I have module.xml as follows:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Product_Api" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogWidget"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
    <module name="Company_Product_Widget" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Company_Product_Api"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

And registration.php as follows:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_Product_Api',
    __DIR__
);
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_Product_Widget',
    __DIR__
);
```

EDIT 2:
So based on Marius' Answer i've ended up with the following. I am not sure its 100% right yet as the API is returning me a 400 error.

```
- /Company
  - /Product
    - registration.php
    - /etc
      - di.xml
      - module.xml
      - webapi.xml
      - widget.xml
    - /Api
    - /Block
    - /Model
    - /view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`etc` has to be inside the module folder.
You have `Company/Module/etc`.
Otherwise it does not work.
Same goes for `registration.php`

Comment: So can I have multiple "\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register" in registration.php and multiple config\module elements in module.xml?

Comment: PS I edited the question based on your response and my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You must create 2 directories here to register two different modules.

You can follow this structure here..

In your `app/code` directory you can create your **Vendor/Company** name directory first like..

> app/code/Company/

In that directory you can create multiple modules there like `Widget` and `Api` both are your two different module here in your case. You can choose whatever name here you can use something like this `ProductWidget` and `ProductApi`. You can create these modules inside your **Company** directory here

> app/code/Company/Widget

or

> app/code/Company/ProductApi

Now you need to create `module.xml` file to declare your new module

- Magento 2 looks for configuration information for each module in that module’s `etc` directory. so we need to add `module.xml` file here in module

> app/code/Company/Widget/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Widget" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

Inside module's root directory you need to create this file `registration.php`

- All Magento 2 module must be registered in the Magento system through the magento `ComponentRegistrar` class. This file will be placed in module's root directory.

> app/code/Company/Widget/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_Widget',
    __DIR__
);
```

So finally you can follow below structure for your custom module in `app/code` directory..

- /Company

  - /ProductApi

    - registration.php
    - /etc
    - di.xml
    - module.xml
    - webapi.xml
  - /ProductWidget

    - registration.php
    - /etc
    - module.xml
    - widget.xml

And your `ProductApi` module's `module.xml` file's content should be..

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_ProductApi" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogWidget"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

and `registration.php` file's content..

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_ProductApi',
    __DIR__
);
```

And your `ProductWidget` module's `module.xml` file's content should be..

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_ProductWidget" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Company_ProductApi"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

and `registration.php` file's content..

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_ProductWidget',
    __DIR__
);
```

You can check this simple module which I've created on [GitHub](https://github.com/KishanSavaliya/magehelper-magento2-print-hello-world). There is some more information available.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: So what you are saying is that I cant deploy a module that consists of both a widget and an API?

Comment: You can create two modules inside your Vendor means Company's directory. You can not create 2 modules inside single directory.

Comment: Im only wanting to deploy 1 Module. My question is, can a Module consist of a Widget and API eg can it include webapi.xml and widget.xml.

Comment: Then you can create **Company_ProductApi** only this module and you can use **webapi.xml and widget.xml** files there inside this module

Comment: Yes I think I have what I want based on Marius' comments earlier. I'm just fighting a 400 error that I am not sure is part of this problem or something else. Will raise another post for that.

Comment: Okay, You can create single module and you can use webapi and widget both inside that module and you can create 2 modules inside single vendor directory. Both option will work in your case.